# In MySQL is it possible to auto increment in pairs?

Tags: mysql

I have match_id which always comes in pairs.  Instead of incrementing as follows:

1,2,3,4...

Is it possible to increment like this:

1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4

If not how can I guarantee that I will always have at most two identical match_id.  I've tried to implement a Manual solution in code but occasionally I get three at a time if there is a collision.

This is not a primary key.  However I want the match_id to come in pairs so that if I look up match 56, it will show the following:

```
match_id, user_id, score
56, 29, 434
56, 49, 516
```

Dividing by two is a possible solution although it makes the queries really messy.  For example searching for match 56 becomes really convoluted

Comment: Can you be more descriptive? Primary Keys are not allowed to have duplicates. If this isn't a key field you could use a counter field and divide by 2, casting to an integer.

Comment: amended to be more descriptive

Comment: Searching for a specific number is not that messy `WHERE match_id IN (56 * 2, 56 * 2 - 1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that you cannot autoincrement in pairs like that. However, you can easily treat a column that has 1,2,3,4,... as if it had 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,... by using `FLOOR((match_id+1)/2)` instead of `match_id`. You can either use that expression in your data retrieval statements or else denormalize your data base and define a column where you insert that value along with the autoincrement value.